# Retrieve file from GridFS and pass as regular IO::File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, gridfs

I am storing, amongst others, Excel files using GridFs. I'd like to use the Spreadsheet gem to parse these.

I've tried this, but it (obviously!) did not work:

```
1.9.3p194 :036 > db = Mongo::Connection.new.db(Mongoid.database.name)
1.9.3p194 :037 > grid = Mongo::GridFileSystem.new(db)
1.9.3p194 :038 > f = grid.open('test1.xls', 'r')
 => #<GridIO _id: 500ef7cdc5ebb515c9000005>
1.9.3p194 :039 > Spreadsheet.open(f)
NoMethodError: undefined method `flush' for #<GridIO _id: 500ef7cdc5ebb515c9000005>
```

Would you have a good suggestion to 'transform' or 'wrap' the GridIO class into an IO::File -like instance so that I can pass the Excel file to the Spreadsheet open method.

The spreadsheet open method takes either an IO instance or a String specifying the path on disk (the latter not being useful when using GridFS):

```
(Object) open(io_or_path, mode = "rb+", &block)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a desired feature of the ruby driver that doesn't exist yet.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-368

You could probably pass a block to Spreadsheet.open, as is suggested in the jira ticket:

```
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db(Mongoid.database.name)
Spreadsheet.open('filename', 'w') do |f|
   gridfs = Mongo::GridFileSystem.new(db)
   gridfs_file = gridfs.open('test1.xls', 'r')
   f.write(gridfs_file.read()) until gridfs_file.eof?
end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction! I ended up with the suggestion on that page to use a temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

Emily's pointer was quite helpful. For the time being, ended up using a temporary file:

```
Tempfile.open(["test", ".xls"]) do |fh|
 gridfs = Mongo::GridFileSystem.new(Mongoid.database)
 gridfs_file = gridfs.open('test1.xls', 'r')
 fh.binmode
 fh.write(gridfs_file.read)
 @xls = Excel.new(fh)
 fh.close
end
```